# how to split tuple in python and get data with column name

Tags: python, mysql, split, tuples

```
import cv2
import NumPy as np
import face_recognition
import os
from DateTime import DateTime
from SQL import mydb

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT name, age,imageURL,gender FROM staff")
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

name = myresult[0]
age = myresult[1]
imgs = myresult[2]
gender = myresult[3]
```

Need to split my tuple coming from mySQl

Current Result:

```
[(2, 'Joe', '30', 'Male', 'images/Joe.jpg'), (3, 'Doe', '28', 'Male', 'images/Doe.jpg')]
```

Required:

```
(2, 'Joe', '30', 'Male', 'images/Joe.jpg')
(3, 'Doe', '28', 'Male', 'images/Doe.jpg')
```

After that need to have it into columns

```
ID Name Age Gender imageURL 
2  Joe  30  Male   images/Joe.jpg
3  Doe  28  Male   images/Doe.jpg
```

After applying Justin's suggestion:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database = "face_db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM staff")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for (ID, Name, Age, Gender, imageURL) in myresult:
    print(ID,Name,Age,Gender,imageURL)
```

From here I have got separate ID,Name, Age & Gender but missing the column name

Comment: You forgot to include your Python code. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please put what you have tried so far? What is the problem with your own code?

Comment: Are you trying to "display" you result, in STDOUT for example?

Comment: Actually, I have made a Face recognition program. Its working fine when I am fetching images from the hard coded directory.

Now i am trying to get image and other relevant information from the DB itself. 

the pasted data is from the database cursor.

Comment: To unpack a tuple you do, e.g., `for (ID, Name, Age, Gender, imageURL) in cursor: print(...)`

Comment: @JustinEzequie l did followed your suggestion and it given me the list as required except for the column names

Comment: But you already know the column names as you've done a `select` from your table. What's stopping you from printing the column names yourself? Post your code if you cannot figure that out then maybe we can help more.

Comment: When I look at the description of your current result and your required result I have the feeling that you confuse the representation of the data with the content of the data.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel let me go step by step.

1) I am trying to make a face recognition program
2) I have placed the people information i.e (Name, Age, imageURL and Gender) in the database.
3) Now I am fetching the people's list from SQL querry. Which is coming in a tuple
4) Since people's data can be infinite. I am running a loop where I can get information of person according to face matched.
5) I am not getting the Name, Age, Gender by terms of face got detected and can't populate the data accordingly.

Comment: "except for the column names" -- but you already know the column names! What's stopping you from printing the column names *before* you start looping over the cursor results? Update your code to show what you are missing.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel pasted the code

Comment: So what's stopping you from doing `print("ID","Name","Age","Gender","imageURL")` before your `for` loop?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel got it! (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called tuple unpacking.

```py
print("ID", "Name", "Age", "Gender", "imageURL") # print your headers
for (ID, Name, Age, Gender, imageURL) in myresult:
    print(ID, Name, Age, Gender, imageURL) # print the values
```